# Creating SDL_Surface with small width and height causes an error. What should i do?

Tags: sdl, sdl-2

I'm trying to make a method to save a texture by converting the texture to a surface, but if the texture size is less than 100 (or so), it throws an error and the file is not saved.

```
void Graphics::saveTexture(SDL_Texture* texture, const std::string& file_path, Uint32* pixels) {
    int width, height;
    uint32_t format;
    SDL_QueryTexture(texture, &format, NULL, &width, &height);
    SDL_Texture* rendered_texture = SDL_CreateTexture(renderer_, format, SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STREAMING, width, height);

    SDL_SetRenderTarget(renderer_, rendered_texture);
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer_, kClearColor[0], kClearColor[1], kClearColor[2], SDL_ALPHA_OPAQUE);
    SDL_RenderClear(renderer_);
    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer_, texture, NULL, NULL);

    SDL_Surface* surface = SDL_CreateRGBSurfaceWithFormat(0, width, height, SDL_BYTESPERPIXEL(format), format); // here
    SDL_RenderReadPixels(renderer_, NULL, surface->format->format, surface->pixels_, surface->pitch);
    SDL_SaveBMP(surface, file_path.c_str());
    
    SDL_SetRenderTarget(renderer_, NULL);

    SDL_DestroyTexture(rendered_texture);
    SDL_FreeSurface(surface);
}
```

Comment: You should inspect values you pass to function that you think behaves in undesireable way, and check what `SDL_GetError` have to say after this failing call. Documentation for `SDL_CreateRGBSurfaceWithFormat` says `depth` parameter is in bits, yet you use `SDL_BYTESPERPIXEL` macro.

Comment: I fixed the bug, but now the saved surface changes all texture colors (except white) to transparent. Any ideas?

Comment: Check error codes for all functions you use and if SDL returns an error check what `SDL_GetError` gives you. There is no `pixels_` in SDL_Surface, so clearly the code you use is not the one we see. Textures created with `SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STREAMING` can't be used as render targets. Consider making minimal reproducible example, including your picture file and the result you're getting.